# How test if map component loaded?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

`Map` is a custom component that also places and loads a marker with the label "hello". I am also using the `@googlemap-react/core` library.

I am trying to write a test using `jest` and `@testing-library/react` to check if `Map` has loaded. I tried using the queries (`getByText` and `getByLabelText`) but only get this result (or something similar):

[image]

In particular, I thought the `ByLabelText` should work, but either it doesn't with marker labels, or my nascent understanding of testing is inadequate to understand what I should be doing for this test.

Using the tools I'm using:
1) Is there a way to use an `@t-l/r` query to accomplish my goal?
2) How do I test if `Map` has rendered?

Here is my [Map.unit.test.js](https://pastebin.com/ZVGkehpC)

Comment: I would mock the map to see if it gets rendered

Comment: Wouldn't that skip testing if I actually obtain results from Google (in this case)? In my mind, that is part of what I'm testing.

Comment: @Gpx Ok. I'm seeing the point of mocking it. Now I just have to figure out how to do that :-)

Comment: I wrote about how to mock custom selects. The idea is the same but you will render a fake map instead. https://www.polvara.me/posts/testing-a-custom-select-with-react-testing-library/